# Gas cost of checking array length in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, gas

I'm working on minimizing gas costs. I know that if I'm going to be using a storage value more than once it is useful to SLOAD it to a temporary variable. My question is, is it worth it to do the same with array length?

Say I have an array nums[] with variable length. I use that length for a few different operations. Should I just use nums.length, or should I set numLength = nums.length and then use that? In particular I'd love to know whether this temp variable business would be useful if nums is an array in memory.

Comment: Write the code and measure the cost using sensible parameters for your particular use case. Sometimes using a local variable will be cheaper, sometimes it will not, sometimes using a local variable causes stack too deep. There's no general rule that applies in all cases.